# Wordpress Gutenberg - Open the "Block Pattern Explorer" programmatically

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I would like to open the « Patterns Explorer" programmatically when clicking on the "Add Block" button (screen-1).

By default, a click on this button opens the "Block Inserter" (screen-2).
The composition explorer is located in the "Patterns" tab by clicking on "Expore ». (see screen-3 & screen-4)

I manage to open the "Block Inserter" programmatically with the following JS:

```
wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post').setIsInserterOpened(true);
```

But I can't find anything to open "Block Pattern Explorer".

#### Screens

[image: screen-1]
[image: screen-2]
[image: screen-3]
[image: screen-4]

Comment: Did you come up with a solution?

Comment: No, not yet unfortunately